# How to get numbers of variants numerical combinations in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I need to implement a function that accepts two parameters - the number of `0` and the number of `1` and determine how many ways to place these `0` and `1` so that there are no two zeros in a row.

For example, I need to find all methods of placing two `0` and two `1`.

There are six possible ways to place them: `0011`, `0101`, `0110`, `1001`, `1010`, `1100`.

In three cases there are two zeros in a row: `0011`, `1001` and `1100`.

I subtract them from the total number and get three possible ways: `0101`, `0110` and `1010`. So the answer is `3`.

First, I'm trying to write script to recognize which cases I need

```js
let arr = ["1100","1010","1001","0011","0101","0110"]
let result = [];
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
  let expVal = arr[i];
  for (let p = 0; p < expVal.length; p++){
    if (expVal[p] === expVal[p++] || expVal[p] === "0"){
      result.push(expVal)
    }
  } 
}
console.log(result);
```

It's does not work. I don't know how to fix it.
And I don't understand what I need to do later

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you are solving is equivalent to the Fibonacci sequence.

filter for includes '00'

recursive function x generates binary number strings using `n0` zeroes, `n1` ones.  Works by branching to (add a zero, find combos for one less zero)`'0'+x(n0-1,n1)` and (add a one, find combos for one less 1)`'1'+x(n0,n1-1)`.

```js
let arr = ["1100","1010","1001","0011","0101","0110"]

const x = (n0,n1) =>
  !(n0 === 0 || n1 === 0) ?
    x(n0-1,n1).map(x=>'0'+x).concat(
    x(n0,n1-1).map(x=>'1'+x))
    : ['0'.repeat(n0)||'1'.repeat(n1)]

arr = x(2,2)

console.log(
x(2,2)
)

console.log(arr.filter(x=>x.includes('00')))
```

Comment: thank you for reply. Do you how to get an array of all combinations from two zeros and two ones?

Comment: recursive function for generating digits was added

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 issues with the code, as far as I can see:

- You're incrementing `p` two times: once in the `for` definition, and once in the execution itself (`p++`). The second one should be replaced by `p+1`
- Also, you're checking if the next character is equal to the current, `OR` the current character is `0`. This should be `AND`.

  ```js
  let arr = ["1100","1010","1001","0011","0101","0110"]
  let result = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    let expVal = arr[i];
    for (let p = 0; p < expVal.length; p++){
      if (expVal[p] === expVal[p+1] && expVal[p] === "0"){
        result.push(expVal)
      }
    } 
  }
  console.log(result);
  ```

Changing those two things fixes it.

Comment: thank you for reply. But How to get all combinations from two zeros and two ones?